# How to find row containing maximum of subquery value

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table named orders with the fields name and type. The type can either be "remote" or "in-person". I want to get the name of the region that has the most "remote" types for it's orders.

I have done the following:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(order_id) as remote_count
FROM orders
WHERE type = 'remote'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY remote_count DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Which does work but only if one order name has the max remote count. I want to do a query where it accounts for the case if two names equal the max. I DO NOT WANT TO USE A LIMIT

Comment: What MySQL version are you using ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha 5.6

Comment: You should consider upgrading to MySQL 8.x  , where windows functions are supported and queries like this will be much easier. You can see the answers on the duplicated link